# Event handler returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, jquery-events

Let's say I was attaching an event handler of jQuery click event to one of the function of my objects. But why does it return undefined on my properties?

```
var buttonView = {
              label   : 'underscore',
              onClick : function(){ alert('clicked: ' + this.label); },           
        };

$('#bind').bind('click', buttonView.onClick); //clicked: undefined --> why is it undefined ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the function referenced by `buttonView.onClick`, but it's association with `buttonView` *is not retained*.

To retain the reference via `this`,  you can use the [`jQuery.proxy()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) method.

```
$('#bind').bind('click', $.proxy(buttonView,'onClick'));
```

Now `this` in the `onClick` function will refer to your `buttonView` object.

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/K72qs/

---

Or simply make an explicit reference to `buttonView` in the `onClick` function:

```
onClick : function(){ alert('clicked: ' + buttonView.label); },
```

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/K72qs/1/

Answer (score 2):

In the below onclick handler this points to dom element with id "bind" and it do not have a label property. If you have any custom attribute as label you should use $(this).attr("label") to retreieve it. Try this

```
 function(){ alert('clicked: ' + $(this).attr("label")) };
```

Comment: He's trying to get the `label` property of the `buttonView` object.

Comment: That is not possible at all. He has to have a attribute set to the button and use it.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli it can be achieved in the way that @patrick dw says because it happens via closure (be it via proxy or `buttonView`).

Comment: @Lea - I know closure and proxy and it can be used the way Patrick has shown but it was just an example I dont think he needs to do that way. He can use data attributes which is better than relying on closure.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use:

```
 $('#bind')
     .data('label', 'underscore')
     .click(function() {
         alert('clicked: ' + $(this).data('label'));
     });
```