# Javascript:Function in object is undefined when call by onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying on some code here,

```
var cat={
    col:"Red",
    getCol:function(){
        document.writeln(this.col);
    }
}

function getCol(){
    document.writeln(cat.col);
}

$(function(){ 
    $("#button1").click(cat.getCol);
    $("#button2").click(getCol);
})
```

But I got `undefined` for button1, "Red" for button2. Can someone tell me why?

And if I change it into `$("#button1").click(cat.getCol());`, I got the "Red" I need...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's wrong with my event handler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804622/whats-wrong-with-my-event-handler)

Comment: FYI, `$("#button1").click(cat.getCol());` executes `cat.getCol` immediately, not on button click.

Comment: Thanks. it should be something about that 'this' things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all

```
$("#button1").click(cat.getCol);
```

gives you `undefined` because the body of `cat.getCol` uses `this` which ain't `cat` when this thing runs.  I would suggest using `Function.prototype.bind` here, or several of the other variants if you are worried about cross-browser compatibility.  There are many published solutions to the problems of setting "methods" as event handlers and ensuring that `this` stays bound to the enclosing object.

Next

```
$("#button2").click(getCol);
```

works fine because `getCol` uses `cat` directly.

Finally

```
$("#button1").click(cat.getCol());
```

is terribly wrong.  The expression `cat.getCol()` is a *call* which returns `undefined`.  This is not a good value to set for a click handler.  You just saw the document.write taking place, but not in response to a click.

**ADDENDUM**

[Live demo using bind](http://jsfiddle.net/YxzRT/)

Answer (score 1):

Generally in JS, `this` refers to the owner of the function .. So, in both cases when that function is called, `this` would resolve to the (jQuery object of the)element that has been clicked. 
In the first case, `this` is not 'cat', so col is not defined. Thus, it gives undefined.
In the second case, no this, so cat.col resolves to Red.

I think you need to do some reading about JS functions, this, anonymous functions .. http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/ is a good place to start.

This on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this